# Speed of accessing local vs. global variables in gcc/g++ at different optimization levels

Tags: c++, c, optimization, gcc, g++

I found that different compiler optimization levels in gcc give quite different results when accessing a local or a global variable in a loop. The reason this surprised me is that if access to one type of variable is more optimizable than access to another, I would think gcc optimization would exploit that fact. 
Here come two examples (in C++ but their C counterparts give practically the same timings):

```
    global = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        global++;
```

which uses a global variable `long global`, versus

```
    long tmp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        tmp++;
    global = tmp;
```

At optimization level -O0 the timing is essentially equal (as I would expect), at -O1 it is somewhat faster but still equal, but from -O2 the version using the global variable is much faster (a factor 7 or so).

On the other hand, in the following code fragments where start points to a block of bytes of size SIZE:

```
    global = 0;
    for (const char* p = start; p < start + SIZE; p++)
        global += *p;
```

versus

```
    long tmp = 0;
    for (const char* p = start; p < start + SIZE; p++)
        tmp += *p;
    global = tmp;
```

Here at -O0 the timings are close, though the version using the local variable is slightly faster, which doesn't seem too surprising, as maybe it will be stored in a register, whereas `global` wouldn't. Then at -O1 and higher the version using a local variable is considerably faster (more than 50% or 1.5 times). As remarked before, this surprises me, because I would think that for gcc it would be as easy as for me to use a local variable (in the generated optimized code) to assign to the global one later on.

So my question is: what is it about global and local variables that makes that gcc can only perform certain optimizations to one type, not the other?

Some details that may or may not be relevant: I used gcc/g++ version 3.4.5 on a machine running RHEL4 with two single core processors and 4GB RAM. The value I used for SIZE, which is a preprocessor macro, was 1000000000. The block of bytes in the second example was dynamically allocated.

Here are some timing outputs for optimization levels 0 to 4 (in the same order as above):

```
$ ./st0
Result using global variable: 1000000000 in 2.213 seconds.
Result using local variable:  1000000000 in 2.210 seconds.
Result using global variable: 0 in 3.924 seconds.
Result using local variable:  0 in 3.710 seconds.
$ ./st1
Result using global variable: 1000000000 in 0.947 seconds.
Result using local variable:  1000000000 in 0.947 seconds.
Result using global variable: 0 in 2.135 seconds.
Result using local variable:  0 in 1.212 seconds.
$ ./st2
Result using global variable: 1000000000 in 0.022 seconds.
Result using local variable:  1000000000 in 0.552 seconds.
Result using global variable: 0 in 2.135 seconds.
Result using local variable:  0 in 1.227 seconds.
$ ./st3
Result using global variable: 1000000000 in 0.065 seconds.
Result using local variable:  1000000000 in 0.461 seconds.
Result using global variable: 0 in 2.453 seconds.
Result using local variable:  0 in 1.646 seconds.
$ ./st4
Result using global variable: 1000000000 in 0.063 seconds.
Result using local variable:  1000000000 in 0.468 seconds.
Result using global variable: 0 in 2.467 seconds.
Result using local variable:  0 in 1.663 seconds.
```

**EDIT**
This is the generated assembly for the first two snippets with switch -O2, the case where the difference is largest. For as far as I understand, it looks like a bug in the compiler: 0x3b9aca00 is SIZE in hexadecimal, 0x80496dc must be the address of global. 
I checked with a newer compiler, and this doesn't happen anymore. The difference in the second pair of snippets is similar however.

```
    void global1()
    {
        int i;
        global = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
            global++;
    }

    void local1()
    {
        int i;
        long tmp = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
            tmp++;
        global = tmp;
    }

    080483d0 <global1>:
     80483d0:   55                      push   %ebp
     80483d1:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
     80483d3:   c7 05 dc 96 04 08 00    movl   $0x0,0x80496dc
     80483da:   00 00 00 
     80483dd:   b8 ff c9 9a 3b          mov    $0x3b9ac9ff,%eax
     80483e2:   89 f6                   mov    %esi,%esi
     80483e4:   83 e8 19                sub    $0x19,%eax
     80483e7:   79 fb                   jns    80483e4 <global1+0x14>
     80483e9:   c7 05 dc 96 04 08 00    movl   $0x3b9aca00,0x80496dc
     80483f0:   ca 9a 3b 
     80483f3:   c9                      leave  
     80483f4:   c3                      ret    
     80483f5:   8d 76 00                lea    0x0(%esi),%esi

    080483f8 <local1>:
     80483f8:   55                      push   %ebp
     80483f9:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
     80483fb:   b8 ff c9 9a 3b          mov    $0x3b9ac9ff,%eax
     8048400:   48                      dec    %eax
     8048401:   79 fd                   jns    8048400 <local1+0x8>
     8048403:   c7 05 dc 96 04 08 00    movl   $0x3b9aca00,0x80496dc
     804840a:   ca 9a 3b 
     804840d:   c9                      leave  
     804840e:   c3                      ret    
     804840f:   90                      nop
```

Finally here is the code of the remaining snippets, now generated by gcc 4.3.3 using -O3 (though the old version seems to generate similar code). It looks like indeed global2(..) compiles to a function accessing the global memory location in every iteration of the loop, where local2(..) uses a register. It is still not clear to me why gcc wouldn't optimize the global version using a register anyway. Is this just a lacking feature, or would it really lead to unacceptable behaviour of the executable?

```
    void global2(const char* start)
    {
        const char* p;
        global = 0;
        for (p = start; p < start + SIZE; p++)
            global += *p;
    }

    void local2(const char* start)
    {
        const char* p;
        long tmp = 0;
        for (p = start; p < start + SIZE; p++)
            tmp += *p;
        global = tmp;
    }

    08048470 <global2>:
     8048470:   55                      push   %ebp
     8048471:   31 d2                   xor    %edx,%edx
     8048473:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
     8048475:   8b 4d 08                mov    0x8(%ebp),%ecx
     8048478:   c7 05 24 a0 04 08 00    movl   $0x0,0x804a024
     804847f:   00 00 00 
     8048482:   8d b6 00 00 00 00       lea    0x0(%esi),%esi
     8048488:   0f be 04 11             movsbl (%ecx,%edx,1),%eax
     804848c:   83 c2 01                add    $0x1,%edx
     804848f:   01 05 24 a0 04 08       add    %eax,0x804a024
     8048495:   81 fa 00 ca 9a 3b       cmp    $0x3b9aca00,%edx
     804849b:   75 eb                   jne    8048488 <global2+0x18>
     804849d:   5d                      pop    %ebp
     804849e:   c3                      ret    
     804849f:   90                      nop    

    080484a0 <local2>:
     80484a0:   55                      push   %ebp
     80484a1:   31 c9                   xor    %ecx,%ecx
     80484a3:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
     80484a5:   31 d2                   xor    %edx,%edx
     80484a7:   53                      push   %ebx
     80484a8:   8b 5d 08                mov    0x8(%ebp),%ebx
     80484ab:   90                      nop    
     80484ac:   8d 74 26 00             lea    0x0(%esi,%eiz,1),%esi
     80484b0:   0f be 04 13             movsbl (%ebx,%edx,1),%eax
     80484b4:   83 c2 01                add    $0x1,%edx
     80484b7:   01 c1                   add    %eax,%ecx
     80484b9:   81 fa 00 ca 9a 3b       cmp    $0x3b9aca00,%edx
     80484bf:   75 ef                   jne    80484b0 <local2+0x10>
     80484c1:   5b                      pop    %ebx
     80484c2:   89 0d 24 a0 04 08       mov    %ecx,0x804a024
     80484c8:   5d                      pop    %ebp
     80484c9:   c3                      ret    
     80484ca:   8d b6 00 00 00 00       lea    0x0(%esi),%esi
```

Thanks.

Comment: you sure that's a proper username for this site?

Comment: note that when SIZE and global is nonvolatile, compilers might be able to change the whole loop into a single global += SIZE; statement. Using an ancient gcc and only 4MB of ram makes me wonder what hardware you run this on, since any answer is heavily depending on hardware and possibly other things. That said, you might rather want to analyze the generated assembler code yourself, possibly with a good assembler level profiler.

Comment: Sorry PlasmaHH, I meant to write 4GB. The hardware is a pretty standard HP xw8200 workstation.

Comment: A useful thing to do would be to grab the resulting machine code generated by the compiler in each case (using `objdump` or similar), and add this to your question.

Comment: PlasmaHH is right. For the consecutive increments, gcc 4.5.0 optimizes away the whole loop when using "-O2". Also with that newer gcc, the optimized compiles always showed the same runtime for global and for local variables here. With non-optimized compilations, the versions directly accessing global where a bit faster.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: the question remains why the compiler in that case could change one statement into global += SIZE, but not the other into tmp += SIZE. In fact, I would expect it to be safer to do that with the local variable than the global one.

Comment: Definitely agree with PlasmaHH: Look at the assembly output first thing. Post it here if you want additional input on it.

Comment: @doetoe: look at what the assembler output does. Also note that any "could optimize" is not equal to "is guaranteed to optimize", especially with such ancient compilers. To know what is going on, there is no better thing as to look what is going on.

Comment: @PlasmaHH, Oli Charlesworth, undur_gongor, Kerrek SB: thanks. I'll add some generated assembly to the main post.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: could you elaborate?

Comment: I don't see what makes you think there is a bug in the compiler?

Comment: @PlasmaHH: I have very little experience with machine code, but I would think that80483fb:   b8 ff c9 9a 3b          mov    $0x3b9ac9ff,%eax
     8048400:   48                      dec    %eax
     8048401:   79 fd                   jns    8048400 <local1+0x8>
     8048403:   c7 05 dc 96 04 08 00    movl   $0x3b9aca00,0x80496dc
     804840a:   ca 9a 3b

Comment: @doetoe: but why do you think this is a bug? what do you think this code does differently than what it should do?

Comment: @PlasmaHH: the previous comment didn't come through correctly, here it comes again: I have very little experience with machine code, but I would think that `80483fb: mov $0x3b9ac9ff,%eax`, `8048400: dec %eax`, `8048401: jns 8048400` executes a loop 0x3b9ac9ff = 1000000000 - 1 times, at the end of which the value of %eax is 0 and nothing else is done. In other words, this looks to me to be equivalent to setting %eax to 0. In the next instruction `movl $0x3b9aca00,0x80496dc` the value 0x3b9aca00 = 1000000000 is loaded into the address of "global". But then again, I hardly know any machine code.

Comment: The code is certainly not optimal, but this is not a bug in the compilers. Compilers evolve, and especially when using ancient ones as gcc 3.x it is to be expected that things don't optimize as good. We are currently at 4.6.1 ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A local variable `tmp` whose address is not taken cannot be pointed to by the pointer `p`, and the compiler can optimize accordingly. It is much more difficult to infer that a global variable `global` is not pointed to, unless it's `static`, because the address of that global variable could be taken in another compilation unit and passed around.

If reading the assembly indicates that the compiler forces itself to load from memory more often than you would expect, and you know that the aliasing it worries about cannot exist in practice, you can help it by copying the global variable into a local variable at the top of the function and using only the local in the rest of the function.

Finally, note that if pointer `p` had been of another type, the compiler could have invoked "strict aliasing rules" to optimize regardless of its inability to infer that `p` does not point to `global`. But because lvalues of type `char` are often used to observe the representation of other types, there is an allowance for this kind of alias, and the compiler cannot take this shortcut in your example.

Comment: Sounds plausible.  But I guess it depends on what `start` is.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth Compared to the version you commented on, I have changed the sentence to "It is much more difficult to infer that a global variable `global` is not pointed to". As you say, it could depend on what `start` is. But the problem of determining whether `*p` aliases with `global` is so difficult in general that the compiler probably does not even try (whereas the "local variable whose address is not taken" criterion is syntactic, local and works very well in practice).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, when the global variable is non-volatile, isn't it only other threads that could change the value while executing? And isn't it the responsibility of the programmer (rather than the compiler) to provide thread safeness?

Comment: @doetoe: the problem is that a global variable may be manipulated indirectly via pointers. If the compiler can prove that there's no write through a pointer that may alias the global, it can still optimize the access. But that's a big _if_

Comment: @doetoe I can only repeat what I said to Oli Charlesworth: if the variable is not static, its address can always be taken in another compilation unit, and then passed around, and end up where you don't expect it. It would still be possible to predict the absence of alias with a global in some cases: in fact, I work on an analysis that does just that (see my bio). But this kind of analysis is extremely difficult, and the compiler may not even try.

Comment: This answer is exactly right.  For all the compiler knows, you might call `global2` with `&global` lying somewhere between `start` and `start+SIZE`.  So the compiler has to emit memory accesses for every loop iteration.  Using `char *` makes this especially hard to optimize because it can alias anything...  Try writing a similar loop with `*start` and `global` being objects of different types, and then the compiler can easily prove the pointers do not alias.

Comment: @Oli Carlesworth, Pascal Cuoq, MSalters, Nemo: Thanks a lot. Until Nemo's comment I didn't understand the other comments, mainly because I couldn't think of any situation (and consequently thought there wasn't any) in which the value of `global` at intermediate stages of the loop could have any influence on the result. Now I realize all of you were explaining me in which situation this could happen.

Comment: @MSalters: It's too bad the Standard doesn't allow extern or global variables to have a "register" qualifier, since if the semantics were such that a compiler could keep its value cached in registers across pointer accesses of any type, that would enable many useful optimizations that would be otherwise unavailable.

Answer (score 12):

Global variable = global memory, and subject to aliasing (read as: bad for the optimizer -- must read-modify-write in the worst case).

Local variable = register (unless the compiler really can't help it, sometimes it must put it on the stack too, but the stack is practically guaranteed to be in L1)

Accessing a register is on the order of a single cycle, accessing memory is on the order of 15-1000 cycles (depending on whether the cache line is in cache and not invalidated by another core, and depending on whether the page is in the TLB).

Comment: Sounds plausible. But I guess it depends on what `start` is.