# Why are local variables accessed faster than global variables in lua?

Tags: lua, global-variables, local-variables

So I was reading *Programing in Lua 2nd Ed* and I came across this paragraph here:

> It is good programming style to use local variables whenever
>   possible. Local variables help you avoid cluttering the global
>   environment with unnecessary names.  Moreover, **the access to local
>   variables is faster than to global ones**.

Could anyone explain why this is? And is this "feature" only in Lua, or is it in other languages aswell? (e.g. C, C++, Java)

Comment: Some discussion of speed of access in c++ - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241035/speed-of-accessing-local-vs-global-variables-in-gcc-g-at-different-optimizati I guess the same issues that apply in c++ would apply to language, though I'm no expert in this area.

Comment: I think this might help. I believe the idea is language agnostic:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/41148360/7298156

Comment: I think this might help. I believe it is a language agnostic idea:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/41148360/7298156

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The difference in running time is due to the difference between hash table lookup and array lookup. An interpreter might be able to place a local variable in a CPU register, but even without such cleverness local variables are faster to access.

Global variables in Lua are stored in tables. Generally, anyone can modify these tables, and therefore the interpreter has to lookup a value anew every time it is being accessed. Local variables on the other hand disappear only when they go out of scope. Therefore they can have fixed locations in an array.

The benchmark program below calls a dummy function in a loop. The benchmark shows how the running time goes up the more tables the program has to jump through.

Other dynamic languages should be expected to have similar characteristics; see for example the Python benchmark at the very end.

Some relevant links:

- [Optimising Using Local Variables](http://lua-users.org/wiki/OptimisingUsingLocalVariables) (Lua)
- [Local Variables](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Local_Variables) (Python performance tips)
- [Optimizing Global Variable/Attribute Access.](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0266/) A (withdrawn) Python proposal on the lookup of global vs. local objects.

File `demo.lua`:

```
local M = {}
_G.demo = M
function M.op(x) return x end
return M
```

File `main.lua`:

```
local M = require "demo"

op = demo.op

local outer_op = demo.op

function iter_op(n)
    local inner_op = demo.op
    for i = 1, n do
        -- Example running times for n = 100,000,000 (Lua 5.2.0):

        -- Lookup a table (demo or _G), then lookup 'op'
        -- within that table:
        --
        -- demo.op(i)      --> 0:40
        -- _G.op(i)        --> 0:39

        -- Lookup 'op' within a known local table (M or the table of
        -- globals):
        --
        -- M.op(i)         --> 0:30
        -- op(i)           --> 0:30

        -- Dereference a local variable declared inside or outside
        -- of this iter_op() function:
        --
        -- inner_op(i)     --> 0:23
        -- outer_op(i)     --> 0:22
    end
end

iter_op(100000000)
```

File `main.py`:

```py
import demo # Contains 'def op(x): return x'.

global_op = demo.op

def iter_op(n):
    local_op = demo.op
    for i in xrange(n):
        # Example running times for n = 50,000,000 (Python 2.6.5):
        # demo.op(i)     # 0:50
        # global_op(i)   # 0:41
        local_op(i)      # 0:36

iter_op(50000000)
```

Answer (score 8):

In any language local variables will be faster. You will need to understand what a [register](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_register) is and what the thread [stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-based_memory_allocation) is to understand my explanation. Most local variables are implemented as a register variable or pushed near the top of the local stack, so they are generally accessed much more quickly. Global variables are stored further up the stack (if they are not on the heap) so computing their address to access them is slower.

I'm making some assumptions here about the inner workings of Lua, but this makes sense from a computer architecture standpoint.

Comment: Yeah, I think Lua actually runs on a register-based VM, so that would make sense.

Comment: @Jdc1197: It's sort of a hybrid register/stack thing. It has a stack, but most of its functions can modify things that aren't on the top of the stack. Thus the stack is really just a grow-able register file.