# Explanation about “local foo = foo” idiom in Lua

Tags: lua

In *Programming in Lua (3rd Ed.)* by Roberto Ierusalimschy it is stated that

> A common idiom in Lua is
>
> `local foo = foo`
>
> This code creates a local
>   variable, `foo`, and initializes it with the value of the global
>   variable `foo`. (The local `foo` becomes visible only after its
>   declaration.) This idiom is useful when the chunk needs to preserve
>   the original value of `foo` even if later some other function changes
>   the value of the global `foo`; it also speeds up the access to `foo`.

**Could someone explain this more in detail and provide a simple example?**

At the moment, the only use I can think of for this idiom is to manage local variables (in a given block) that have the same names as global variables, so that the global variable is left unchanged after the block.

An example:

```
foo = 10
do
   local foo = foo
   foo = math.log10(foo)
   print(foo)
end
print(foo)
```

this gives:

```
1
10
```

But the same could be accomplished without using the idiom at all:

```
bar = 10
do
   local bar = math.log10(bar)
   print(bar)
end
print(bar)
```

that gives the same result. So my explanation doesn't seem to hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation is correct; I'm not sure why you are not satisfied with your example. To give you a real example:

```
local setfenv = setfenv
if not setfenv then -- Lua 5.2+
  setfenv = function() ..... end
end
```

Another reason is to preserve the value as it is at this moment, so that other functions that use that value (in a file or a module) would have the same expectations about that value.

Comment: @PierPaolo, Because the change will be in effect only in the current blog. If you don't do `local setfenv = setfenv`, the effect will be visible outside of the current block, which is not desirable in this case.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen this used more often as a optimization technique than as a way to preserve original values. With the standard Lua interpreter, every global variable access and module access requires a table lookup. Local variables, on the other hand, have statically-known locations at bytecode-compile time and can be placed in VM registers.

In more depth: [Why are local variables accessed faster than global variables in lua?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132288/why-are-local-variables-accessed-faster-than-global-variables-in-lua)

Answer (score 2):

Wrapping a global:

```
do
  local setmetatable = setmetatable
  function _ENV.setmetatable(...)
    -- Do your thing
    return setmetatable(...)
  end
end
```

Reducing overhead by using a local instead of doing a lookup in the globals-table (which is a local btw.):

```
local type = type
for k, v in next, bigtable do
  if type(v) == "string" then
    -- Do one thing
  else
    -- Do other thing
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're splitting hairs, unintentionally.

`local bar = math.log10(bar)`

is essentially the same as `local bar = bar` in spirit, but we it would be less useful to claim that the idiom is `local bar = a(bar)`, because we may want to handle the local in some way other than passing it to a function first --  e.g. appending it to something.

This point is that we want to refer to the local `bar`, just as you say, not exactly how the conversion from global to local is done.