# Are global variables faster than local variables in C?

Tags: c, variables, scope, global-variables, lifetime

I had a couple thoughts on this.  The first is that allocating global variables may be faster, since they are only allocated once, at the time the program is first spawned, whereas local variables must be allocated every time a function is called.  My second thought is that since local variables are on the stack, they are accessed through the base pointer register, so the value stored in the base pointer must be decremented every time a local variable is accessed; global variables are accessed directly through their static addresses in the data segment.  Is my thinking accurate?

Comment: The question that can be answered by "Yes" or "No" is a *bad* question for SO format.

Comment: Yes specially because you left any explanation out of the scope. You should trust your understanding too, you are reasoning cleanly about it and it does make sense. So why ask?

Comment: It depends on many factors, but usually it is pointless to care about this.

Comment: Totally depends on the cache behavior. Both could be like 100x faster than the other based on the usage pattern.

Comment: There is no "stack". There are only objects with *automatic storage duration*, which may be kept in registers if their address is never taken. On practically all processor architectures, accessing a register is much faster than the memory access required for accessing an object with *static storage duration* like a global.

Comment: There is no extra work to "allocate" a value on the stack.  The stack pointer is just moved by a different number.  Access time is the same to offset a value by the stack pointer as to offset it by a data segment register.  So your thinking is mostly wrong.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's rather inaccurate.

If you study computer architecture, you'll find out that the fastest storage are the registers, followed by the caches, followed by the RAM. The thing about local variables is that the compiler optimizes them to be allocated from the registers if possible, or from the cache if not. This is why local variables are faster.

For embedded systems, sure it might be possible to compile to a tiny memory model in which case your data segment may possibly fit into a modern controller's SRAM cache. But in such cases, your local variable usage would also be very tight such that they are probably operating entirely on registers.

Conclusion: In most cases, local variables will be faster than global variables.

Comment: what if a variable is too big to be kept inside registers? Lets say I create int[10000] array and iterate over it in the loop. If array is created locally on every function call, it's probably going to be slower than allocate same array once in global space and then reuse it.

Comment: In such cases, the developer should dynamically allocate the variable and pass around the pointer. Putting it in the stack (local variable) is not a good idea due to its limited size. Making it global is not a good idea either unless it really is a constant.

Comment: You're right @LeonCarloValencia. Nevertheless, dynamically allocation should not be used under some directives (MISRA). In this case, what I do is declaring the array inside the function scope as static instead of global.

Comment: This makes somewhat baseless assumptions on what the compiler will optimize. If the compiler sees a global variable being repeatedly accessed, then unless it is explicitly marked `volatile`, it is just as likely to optimize that into a register as a stack/local variable.