# Lua and conditional "compilation" : need clarification

Tags: debugging, lua

I understood that there is no preprocessor in LUA, so nothing like #define and so on.
But I'd like to have "debug" options. For example, I'd like an optional console debug like :

```
if do_debug then
  function msg(s) 
    print(s) 
  end
else
  function msg(s) 
  end
end

msg(string.format(".............",v1,v2,......))
```

It works, but I wonder what is the CPU cost in "no debug" mode.
The fact is that I call a lot of these msg() function with large strings, sometimes built and formated with a lot of variables. So I would like to avoid extra work. But I suppose that LUA is not clever enough to see that my function is empty, and that there's no need to build its parameter...

So is there a turnaround to avoid these extra costs in LUA ?

NB : you may say that the CPU cost is negligible, but I'm using this for a realtime audio process and CPU does matter in this case.

Comment: The cost is indeed the one of a function call. You correctly say that Lua does not have a preprocessor. It used to have a long time ago, before 4.0 or so. But nothing prevents you to run C preprocessor on a Lua source file! this is just a matter to modify the makefile. I already did that in the past.

Comment: While it's definitely not a recommended solution, you could just gsub all your debug lines away before loading the code. If you have just a few files, create your own require/dofile function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't avoid the creation and unwinding of the stack frame for the `msg` function.
But what you can improve, at least in the snippet shown, is moving the `string.format` call into `msg`:

```lua
if do_debug then
  function msg(...)
    print(string.format(...))
  end
else
  function msg() end
end

msg(".............",v1,v2,......)
```

---

Another approach, trading readability for performance, would be to always do the `if do_debug` right where you want to print the debug message. A conditional check is much faster than a function call.

---

But the only way to truly avoid the function call that I know of would be to compile your own version of the Lua interpreter, with a (at least rudimentary) preprocessor added to the parser.

Comment: I forgot the simple `if do_debug` solution !  It will help.

And I did not know about the variable number of arguments. Thanks for this !

Compiling the LUA interpreter would not be possible because I already use a LUA interpreter embedded in a software that I do not control...

Comment: Also keep in mind if `do_debug` is a global variable and you use it more than once or twice within a file, you'll want to move it to a local variable, e.g `local do_debug = do_debug` somewhere at the top.

Comment: I do not understand why `local do_debug = do_debug` will help. Is it harder to check a global variable ?

And by the way, I have a problem with your solution if my format string contains a single % that is not a format char.

Let say that I want to pass a simple string `msg("hello %")`, without any other parameter...

Comment: global vs local: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132288/why-are-local-variables-accessed-faster-than-global-variables-in-lua

Comment: For the `%`, if you write that string yourself, you can simply escape it as `%%`. If you can't do that, or don't want to, you can use `select` inside the `msg` function to check if there is only a single argument and skip the formatting.

Comment: Thanks. I do not write the string myself, so I cannot be sure that the % will be escaped. So your solution works if the entry is a single string, but what if I want to mix both ? Like `msg("%d percent%",1)`  I tried various combination of string.gsub on arg[1] but did not find the solution...